# How to prevent upload file when form validation false in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter 3.x. when my form submitted if form validation FALSE my uploaded file(s) stay on the host and this is a bug. i am using callback function for upload. thanks for any solutions...

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('file', 'lang:pic',callback_multiple_upload');

//The callback

    public function multiple_upload(){

        $this->load->library('upload');
        $number_of_files_uploaded = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
        // Faking upload calls to $_FILE
        for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files_uploaded; $i++){
            if(!$_FILES['file']['name'][$i])
                continue;
            $_FILES['file[]']['name']     = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['type']     = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['error']    = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['size']     = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

            $config = array(
                'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
                'encrypt_name'  => TRUE,
                'max_size'      => 200,
                'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
                'overwrite'     => FALSE,
                'upload_path'   => "./PATH/");
            $this->upload->initialize($config,TRUE);
            if($this->upload->do_upload("file[]")===FALSE){
                $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
                $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_upload',$error);
                return FALSE;
            }
            else{
                $this->final_files_data[]=$this->upload->data();
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your form validation code

Comment: Post edited and you can see the code now.

Comment: if it helps you roytuts.com/codeigniter-multiple-files-upload/

Comment: Form validation callbacks are for validation not other app logic (such as uploads). Imagine if other elements of your form evaluate to false, the files will keep getting uploaded until the user submits a valid form. The callback will always be called. This messy. Do your validation checks on other elements in the form, then do your upload after that. If there are errors there, then send those errors to the user. Don't try an do all this in form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check that the validation checks return true.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
    //File uploading
} else {
    //Error message or redirection
}
```

Comment: i tried your script { $this->form_validation->run() } in callback function and having this error { Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level }.

Comment: This error message comes specifically from the XDebug extension. PHP itself does not have a function nesting limit. Change the setting in your php.ini:

Comment: xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200

Comment: or in your PHP code:

ini_set('xdebug.max_nesting_level', 200);

Comment: I set 1000 but having memory issue. I just have 3 fields and getting memory limitation warnings. Your solution may work but it create other issues too.I don't know which hosting @Morteza Mousavi using but mostly people use shared hosting.

Comment: just use 200 and then let me know what happen

Comment: By default there is 256 value and I did with 200 value and getting this error. { Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '200' reached, aborting! }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165453/discussion-between-danish-ali-and-adnan-haider).

Comment: i am waiting for your response on chat.

Comment: see answers in chat

Comment: Nothing get relevant answer to the question in chat.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your callback function add your mandatory checks.

```
    public function multiple_upload()
   {
      if (isset($_POST['username'])) // validation checks 
      {
         $this->load->library('upload');
         $number_of_files_uploaded = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
         for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files_uploaded; $i++)
         {
            if (!$_FILES['file']['name'][$i])
               continue;
            $_FILES['file[]']['name'] = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['type'] = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['error'] = $_FILES['file']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file[]']['size'] = $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

            $config = array(
               'allowed_types' => 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif',
               'encrypt_name' => TRUE,
               'max_size' => 200,
               'remove_spaces' => TRUE,
               'overwrite' => FALSE,
               'upload_path' => "./PATH/");
            $this->upload->initialize($config, TRUE);
            if ($this->upload->do_upload("file[]") === FALSE)
            {
               $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
               $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_upload', $error);
               return FALSE;
            } else
            {
               $this->final_files_data[] = $this->upload->data();
            }
         }
         return TRUE;
      } else
      {
         return false;
      }
   }
```